How can I protect a DC/DC converter when VIN is floating?
I'm using a L6902 (https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6902.pdf) to charge a 4 cell lifepo4 pack (with a solid BMS).
Do I need a diode on the converter output (PACK+) to prevent the converter from being damaged when the ac adapter is disconnected, but the battery pack is connected?
Are there any other techniques besides a diode that I could use?
Here's my schematic:


After thinking about this more, could it be as simple as adding a pulldown resistor on VIN/VCC?

You have a DC path from Pack+ through your current sense resistor, the inductor, and the body diode of the top side switch, so it will power Vcc.  I don't think that will damage anything, but it might not be desirable, and your pulldown won't fix the problem.  Since it's not synchronous it can't boost back if the pack voltage is higher than the set voltage, but you might want see what the manufacturer says.

Do you know that disconnecting input is a problem at all? What do the abs. max. ratings say? Block diagram?

Also I hope this isn't intended to charge a lithium battery of any sort, (hooked directly to the pack) since it's not a proper charger and could easily cause issues by not using the correct charge algorithms and techniques.

@JohnD I have this paired with a 4S 3.5AH lifepo4 pack and high quality BMS with a temp sensor. With the above design I should have CC/CV charging up to 1A and 14.2V. What failure modes are you predicting? Anything that a good BMS should not handle?

@alexlroemer One example is if the battery is ever over-discharged.  You can get (short circuit-like) dendrite growth that a charger IC will detect and go into "recovery" mode where the cells are charged at a very low rate until they reach a certain voltage where normal charging resumes.  How and when do you terminate charging?  You can't leave lithium cells on a "float".  Other things a proper charger can do is modify the charge profile based on temperature.  There's no standard definition of a "BMS" so I don't know what yours is capable of.

Thanks, looking at some dedicated lithium charging ICs I see what you mean. It's unclear what will happen if I "float" lifepo4 cells. I will reduce the voltage to 3.3 V per cell and see how it goes. Luckily, this is for an outdoor project where spontaneous combustion is acceptable.

@alexlroemer Float charging probably won't cause a fire, but will reduce the capacity and lifetime of your cells.

Usually there would be two problems. Over current and over voltage.
It's unlikely that over current would be an issue as the DC/DC converter should be current limited and it already has a current sense resistor which would prevent large amounts of current transferring from out to PACK+.
The over voltage condition is a concern, it would be better to test and see if you see overshoot while disconnecting a battery on PACK+ with an oscilloscope. Another problem is if the battery is a higher voltage than the out pin, that would be bad, you need to ensure by design that the battery voltage never exceeds the max voltage of OUT.
If you do see a small amount of overshoot, then add a protection diode.

Thanks, I will have to characterize the disconnect event. I was more worried about how the L6902 will handle the steady state where it's VCC is floating, but the OUT pin is seeing pack voltage.

If you like the answer, please use the voting system
